# nextResponder in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiresponder

in Swift 2 this code works fine

```
override func nextResponder() -> UIResponder? {
  // it's called when user make any touch event
  return super.nextResponder()
}
```

it's basically helps to get notification about any user interaction.

in Swift 3 now it's a variable not a function and I can't even observe it with didSet.

so how to use the code above in Swift 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the variable:

```
override var next: UIResponder? {
    get {
        // do something
        return super.next
    }
}
```

As the variable is defined as a read-only variable, implementing `didSet` doesn't make sense. You're not supposed to set this variable. Instead, different subclasses of `UIResponder` can override the variable and return different values. The base class returns `nil`.

Note: The variable is called `next` in Swift 3 and `nextResponder` in Objective-C and earlier Swift versions. This can be seen in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621099-next) when you switch between *Swift* and *Objective-C* in the right column.

Answer (score 1):

`nextResponder` is replaced by `next` in `Swift 3`. Its new declaration is:

```
var next: UIResponder? { get }
```

Comment: Seems that was a mistake in the translator because other properties like `inputView: UIView?` are not just `input`.