# Responder chain error

Tags: ios, swift, responder-chain

I want to translate this kind of Objective-C code to Swift:

```
- (UINavigationController *)targetNaviCtrl{
    if(!_targetNaviCtrl){
        UIResponder *target = self.nextResponder;
        do {
            target = target.nextResponder;
        } while (![target isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.self] && target != nil);
        _targetNaviCtrl = (UINavigationController *)target;
    }
    return _targetNaviCtrl;
}
// by iterate its next responder, so I can get access the target viewController to do something. 
// This is often used across several hierarchies.
// A root B, B push C , C push D. I use A in D viewController.
```

I met some trouble.

[code repo](https://github.com/dengV/Anima_Ray/archive/v1.8.2.zip)

---

[Apple Doc: next](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621099-next)

> #### Declaration
>
> var next: UIResponder? { get }
>
> #### Return Value
>
> The next object in the responder chain or nil if this is the last object in the chain.

[image: dist]

I want to access the left tarBarController in the right viewController.

#### class ViewControllerEightLayer

// the right viewController.

```
class ViewControllerEightLayer: UIViewController {
    override var next: UIResponder?{
        get{
            return super.next
        }  
}// the right viewController.

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     var nextResponder = self.next! // Here I call it
}
```

### Here I call it, here is error info:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

#### class LayerTableVC

// the center a little right UITableViewController.

```
 class LayerTableVC: UITableViewController {
    override var next: UIResponder?{
        get{
           return super.next
        }
  }// the center a little right UITableViewController.
```

#### class LayerNavigationVC

// the center a little left UINavigationController.

```
 class LayerNavigationVC: UINavigationController {
    override var next: UIResponder?{
        get{
           return super.next
        }
  }// the center a little left UINavigationController.
```

#### class MainTabBarVC

// the left tarBarController

```
 class MainTabBarVC: UINavigationController {
    override var next: UIResponder?{
        get{
           return self
        }
  }// the left tarBarController
```

### I do not know how to solve it in this way. Any suggestions?

---

Maybe It helps,

```
self.next?.target(forAction: <#T##Selector#>, withSender: <#T##Any?#>)
```

It seems wired.

---

I did it by the code ,

```
let tabBarViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

### And I want to know the responder chain solution

---

PS:

### aim of digging through the responder chain is curiosity.

It happened , I do not think it will happen .

So I wonder why.

I'd like to reverse-engineering.

---

PPS:

My intend is to control the tool bar to hide and show.  Not providing data from to

```
 extension ViewControllerEightLayer: UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.text == "1" {
            tabBarViewController.tabBar.isHidden = false
         }
         else{
             tabBarViewController.tabBar.isHidden = true
         }
         return true
   }
```

This is a personal experiment project, not of my corp.

Comment: "I call it, and i failed" Failed how? Found nil?

Comment: I wonder if you're asking the wrong question... Is your intent to provide data from `View Controller Eight Layer` to `Layer Cases View Controller`?

Comment: Having said that, @DonMag is right. What is the aim of digging through the responder chain?

Comment: Updated, @Mr Music & DonMag

Comment: Wait, why would you override `next` to call `super`????

Comment: I googled . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677049/nextresponder-in-swift-3 . And the senmatic is logical .@matt

Comment: No, I don't get it. `next` already exists and does what it does, correctly. Overriding it is just a way to break stuff (which is what you seem to be doing).

Comment: @matt , I build an other project to test it. The result is quite apple doc , not yours. Maybe something I missed . Here is the link https://github.com/dengV/responder_for_stack_over_flow .  Do do hope you can help me to solve it.

Comment: To test _what_? I still have not understood the problem at all. What exactly is the goal?

Comment: I want to get the superior instance （ for example : the root view controller）in the presented view controller through responder chain. The Obj-C code of the start part works perfect.  How to achieve it in swift? `self.next`  , I aways got nil as apple doc. So I override it. How do you say 'next' already exists? @matt

Comment: I say that `next` already exists because it does. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621099-next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking for how to walk up the responder chain. Here's how.

```
func showResponderChain(_ r: UIResponder) {
    var r : UIResponder! = r
    repeat { print(r, "\n"); r = r.next } while r != nil
}
```

Comment: Language is irrelevant.